# Display the responses to the current form inside an embedded view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am trying to create a new Lotus Notes Database (classic, not using XPages) using the Domino designer which will be used to manage customers and orders.

As orders belong to customers, I implemented orders as responses to customers (this seems to be the only way to create a hierarchy).

Now, the form representing the customer should contain a view displaying all the orders which belong to the customer.

However, I don't know how to implement this view:

First, every embedded view based on a formula (I tried `SELECT (Form = "Order")`) creates an error message: "Unable to launch at this time".

Second, I have absolutely no idea how to restrict the result to responses to the **current** Form (in my case: Showing only the orders belonging to the current customer and not all orders in the database).

Comment: I removed the LotusScript tag.  Neither the question nor the answer has any connection to LotusScript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To embed the view in the 'customer form', open that form, place the cursor on the place you want the embedded view, and from the menu select: Create -> Embedded Element -> View...

Select the view you want to embed, and click 'Ok'.

Now, to show only orders for current customer, you will see in the Objects tree list 'Embedded View' with 2 option, select the second 'Show single category'. There you can specify with formula only the current customer. For example, to show entries only for the current logged user I would put:

```
@Name([CN]; @UserName)
```

Hopefully, this info will help solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks - that gave me a hint to the correct direction. I found the answer in http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/869c7412fe5d56b7852569fa007826e3/03e778c86525ce728525704300281c05?OpenDocument - the trick is to group the view you want to embed.

Comment: Nice answer utkai. It remind me the old days that I was working on Lotus Notes heavily!